# Problem using RevTeX4-1 with "! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@bibitemShut"

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I am using RevTeX4-1.

When I typeset the original file, compile the bibliography, and then try to typeset the original file again, I get an error:

> "! Undefined control sequence. < argument> @bibitemShut."

Below is a minimal file with which I get the error, followed by the test `.bib` file that I used, and then followed by the `.bbl` file it outputs. Can anyone help?

(**I am using PcTeX**, which I purchased **many years ago** and no longer seems to have much support available, but which I am very used to. Perhaps this is my problem but I am hoping not, because I'd prefer not to have to get used to a whole new interface.)

I will also mention that when compiling the bibliography, I do get a warning but am guessing this is not the problem. The warning is this:

> ```
> Warning--jnrlst (dependency: not reversed) set 1
>
> merlin.mbs apsrev4-1.bst 2010-07-25 4.21a (PWD, AO, DPC) hacked
>
> Control: key (0) 
>
> Control: author (8) initials jnrlst
>
> Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
>
> Control: production of article title (-1) disabled
>
> Control: page (0) single
>
> Control: year (1) truncated
>
> Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
>
> (There was 1 warning)
> ```

---

Here is my minimal tex file:

```
\documentclass[pra]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here's one citation \cite{Ref1}, and now another one \cite{Ref2}. 

\bibliography{Testrefs}

\end{document}
```

---

And here is my bib file:

```
@ARTICLE{Ref1,
    AUTHOR={Someone1a and Someone1b},
    TITLE={Title1},
    JOURNAL={Journal1},
    VOLUME={44},
    PAGES={5555},
    YEAR={1999}
}

@ARTICLE{Ref2,
    AUTHOR={Someone2a and Someone2b},
    TITLE={Title2},
    JOURNAL={Journal2},
    VOLUME={55},
    PAGES={7777},
    YEAR={2000}
}
```

---

In case it is useful, here is the bbl file created when I compile the bibliography:

```
%merlin.mbs apsrev4-1.bst 2010-07-25 4.21a (PWD, AO, DPC) hacked
%Control: key (0)
%Control: author (8) initials jnrlst
%Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
%Control: production of article title (-1) disabled
%Control: page (0) single
%Control: year (1) truncated
%Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
\begin{thebibliography}{2}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode
  `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{http://dx.doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty
%</preamble>
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Someone1a}\ and\ \citenamefont
  {Someone1b}(1999)}]{Ref1}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {Someone1a}}\ and\
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {Someone1b}},\ }\href@noop {} {\bibfield
  {journal} {\bibinfo  {journal} {Journal1}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume}
  {44}},\ \bibinfo {pages} {5555} (\bibinfo {year} {1999})}\BibitemShut
  {NoStop}%
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Someone2a}\ and\ \citenamefont
  {Someone2b}(2000)}]{Ref2}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {Someone2a}}\ and\
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {Someone2b}},\ }\href@noop {} {\bibfield
  {journal} {\bibinfo  {journal} {Journal2}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume}
  {55}},\ \bibinfo {pages} {7777} (\bibinfo {year} {2000})}\BibitemShut
  {NoStop}%
\end{thebibliography}%
```

Comment: I have not. The reason is that while PcTeX provides info as to how to set things up to use it with revtex4-1, there is no such info with revtex4-2. So I was afraid I would be hopelessly lost trying to figure out the latter.

Comment: Well, gosh, I solved my problem. I added the following line in the preamble, and now everything works perfectly: \newcommand{\BibitemShut}[1]{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not know PcTeX and therefore I do not know which versions of packages are included there.

But after a look to there web page (copyright 2009, last update 2013; telling nothing about used package versions) I simply suggest to not use this very outdated and as it seems unsupported software. Depending on your used computer I suggest to install MiKTeX or TeXLive  ...

With an current MiKTeX on Windows 8 I can compile your MWE without problems, only some warnings that `revtex4-1` misses some parameter ...

Resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]